# Can't create React Typescript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

When I executed command in cmd:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --typescript
```

It's seems like app will be typescript but when I open folder in VS-code then I release that all files in src folder are with *.js* extension instead *.ts(.tsx)* extensions.. I try to create app by cmd(administrator mode) but useless, without change. Also I tried with command:

```
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

Still nothing.

There are no error. App works like standard react+js app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

or:

```
yarn create react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

Comment: Thank you! App start without any problem, but file App.tsx show me some error in code, something like "unreacheble code detection"?

Answer (score 1):

I also got the same error, and tried `npx create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts` as advised above and got the error below:

✔ The react-scripts-ts package is deprecated. TypeScript is now supported natively in Create React App. You can use the --template typescript option instead when generating your app to include TypeScript support. Would you like to continue using react-scripts-ts? … yes
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts-ts with cra-template...

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://npm.community

I then removed create-react-app globally using the below command
**sudo npm uninstall -g create-react-app**

Then

**npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript** and all works well

refer to his guide [enter link description here](https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/setup)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me, did you try **npm uninstall -g create-react-app** first? this will of course uninstall create-react-app globally

[Ading Typescript](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript)